# Losing reputation for a question that I have not answered

Tags: bug

I just noticed that there's an entry on my user page that says I lost 1 reputation for the [question about the difference between rigor and rigorousness](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95530/whats-the-difference-between-rigor-and-rigorousness). I don't have a problem with being downvoted, but **I didn't answer the question**, I merely made a comment. I believe I read recently that upvotes for comments don't add to one's reputation, so I assume that because there's no downvote icon for comments, that there's no way to lose reputation for that either. Can anyone explain what may have happened there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You downvoted, presumably. Both the question and one answer have a downvote, and one of those is probably yours.  Look at your reputation tab, in the detail by post. It should tell you.

Comment: Thank you. I now see that it says "downvoted" instead of "downvote". Now I understand the difference. :-)